# Delete Cortana voice information

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cortana

Is there any way to delete my voice information from Microsoft's servers?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly (it's quite broad), you can do this in Settings > Privacy > Speech, inking & typing > Stop getting to know me.

If that's not enough, the most comprehensive privacy management dashboard Microsoft has is located at http://account.microsoft.com/privacy.

Comment: As far as I know that will _not_ remove my voice data from Microsoft's servers.

Comment: @ispiro See the edit.

Comment: Thanks. There seems to be no way of doing it through the privacy dashboard.

Comment: @ispiro Yeah, I don't see anything definitive there. The closest I can come up with would be here (https://account.microsoft.com/privacy#/cortana) > "Clear Cortana Data".